# How to choose x0 to prove that (log x)² is in Ω(log x + 5)?

Tags: big-o

Is `f(x) = O(g(x))` , `Ω(g(x))` or `Θ(g(x))` ?

```
f(x) = (log x)²
g(x) = log x + 5
```

After graphing it, it shows more than one intersection, and I could not find the x₀.

Comment: Isn't this better suited to Math.SE or CS.SE? It doesn't seem to involve any computer programming code as far as I can see on this small screen...

Comment: Please don't write `f(x) = O(g(x))`.  At least, write `f(x) ∈ O(g(x))`.  It's still incorrect as it should be `f ∈ O(g)` but it seems everybody is making this mistake so we've become used to it.

Answer (score 3):

f(x) = Ω(g(x))

**Method 1**

A simple demonstration:

```
     f(x)
lim ------ = infinite when x -> infinite
     g(x)
```

This is true because if `x -> infinite` => `log(x) = y -> infinite` =>

```
f(x)     y      
---- = ------- -> infinite
g(x)    1+5/y
```

**Method 2**

But if you want to use that approach that uses `c` and `x₀`, just choose some values that don't create any doubts. E.g.:

```
c = 1
x₀ = 1000
```

After some operations, it will become:

```
log(x) ≥ 1 + 5/log(x) for every x ≥ 1000 = x₀
```

which is obviously true.

Of course that the above line is true for b = 2, e, 10, etc., but it is not true for every b. But it's ok, because it's enough to be true for a specified value for b according to the following property:

log<sub>b1</sub>x = log<sub>b2</sub>x / log<sub>b2</sub>b1 and a constant (the denominator) doesn't influence the result (if it is / isn't in `O`, `Ω`or `Θ`).

Or you can choose (according to @AbcAeffchen's answer), x<sub>0</sub> = b<sup>3</sup> and it will be more evident, because 3 ≥ 1 + 5/3.

Comment: The last part is false if the basis `b` of the logarithm is e.g. `b=1000`. But this part becomes true, if you choose `x ≥ b⁵`. just trolling, +1 :)

Comment: Ok, I chose that value according to the most common bases: 2, e, 10... but I'll add some details in the post.